# C++: Correct use of stream operations

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn to use the file stream correctly. The following is a snippet of code that I am maintaining. It works fine, but I was wondering whether the usage is correct and whether there are better ways to perform these tasks. For example, the use of SEEK_SET and ios::beg together. Also, is ios::ate really needed given that the next seek is to the beginning of file.

Could you please help me correct(streamline) the code.

```
ofstream fout(fpath,ios::out| ios::binary | ios::ate);
fout.seekp(SEEK_SET,ios::beg);
fout.write((char*)&test,sizeof(test));

fout.seekp(sizeof(off_t),ios::beg);
fout.write((char*)&temp,sizeof(temp)); //temp is int

fout.seekp((sizeof(off_t)+ sizeof(int)),ios::beg);
fout.write((char*)o,sizeof(MyClass));  

fout.seekp((sizeof(off_t)+ sizeof(int) + sizeof(MyClass)),ios::beg);
fout.write((char*)&l,sizeof(int)); 

fout.close();
```

Comment: I seem to recall that the C standard requires flush or something between seek and write. Check it out.

Comment: @Alf: No, a flush is only required between output and input operations on the same stream, and only when using the `<cstdio>`, not C++ streams. Neither applies here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use the possibilities of the *stream*, for training purposes, then the code is fine.

If you are just trying to write some data, then the *seekp()* method calls are not needed, since the writing pointer will be updated automatically to the end of the last write. *seekp()* is only needed if you need to navigate among records, as in a database, for example.

```
ofstream fout(fpath,ios::out| ios::binary | ios::ate);

fout.write((char*)&test,sizeof(test));
fout.write((char*)&temp,sizeof(temp));
fout.write((char*)o,sizeof(MyClass));
fout.write((char*)&l,sizeof(int)); 

fout.close();
```

This code will work just fine. About problems in your code, you seem to be mixin the C library stdio, with its *fseek()* function, with the *seekp()* and *seekg()* methods. So, it is not very valid to pass SEEK_SET as the first parameter of your call to *seekp()*. In C, you would write:

```
#include <cstdio>

//... 

fseek( f, 5, SEEK_SET );  // from the beginning
fseek( f, -2, SEEK_CUR ); // from the current position
fseek( f, 2, SEEK_CUR );  // from the current position
fseek( f, -2, SEEK_END ); // from the end of the file
```

SEEK_SET will have an int value (implementation-specific, say 2), and therefore, with your line:

```
fout.seekp(SEEK_SET,ios::beg);
```

You're just starting say 2 bytes off the beginning, while your file may or may not have contents when you open it.

About ios::ate, it puts the pointers for reading and writing at the end of the file (you would have to use seekp and seekg to achieve the same behaviour if you needed it, instead of using ios::ate).

Comment: I suppose you mean *records* instead of *registers*?

Comment: Sure. Sorry, too literal spanish translation.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `operator<<` wherever possible.

```
ofstream fout(fpath,ios::out| ios::binary | ios::ate);
fout << test;
fout << temp;    
fout << o;
fout << l;    
fout.close();
```

Not sure what you're doing with the seeking so I cut them for my demonstration, but if you're seeking to the new writing position then it's definitely unnecessary. And there's no way that `SEEK_SET` is a valid C++ Standard library constant- they don't use that naming convention.

Comment: Well, it is standard C++ actually, but only because of the C compatibility features.

Comment: There actually is a very high probability that ios::beg has the same value as SEEK_SET. Not only by coincidence.

Comment: @Bo: even if that were the case, it's being used here as the offset argument, not the direction, which is certainly wrong. It will work by accident if `SEEK_SET` happens to be zero.

Comment: @DeadMG: using the streaming operators gives different behaviour (conversion to text, rather than writing the binary representation). This may not be what's wanted.

Comment: @Mike: He already opened the stream in binary mode. That should output it as binary.

Comment: @DeadMG: the `binary` flag doesn't affect stream formatting; it just allows implementations to handle text and binary streams differently if they want to. Your code will format the data as text.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what others have written, `fout.seekp(sizeof(off_t),ios::beg);` is almost certainly a mistake. It sets the stream output pointer to an implementation-specific number of bytes from the beginning of the stream.